# Couple of Rails issues that i didn't understand

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm just learning rails with [this](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#top) tutorial and there are couple of things i can't understand:

**1- whats the difference between these two assignments? why can i use it in the same helper?**

```
  def current_employee=(employee)
    @current_employee = employee
  end

  def current_employee
    remember_token = Employee.hash(cookies[:remember_token])
    @current_employee ||= Employee.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
  end
```

**2- what's the difference between these 2 update functions, and why the json needed here?**

```
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @employee.update(employee_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @employee, success: 'Employee was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @employee.errors, failure: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

and

```
def update
    @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])
    if @employee.update_attributes(employee_params)
      # Handle a successful update.
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1- whats the difference between these two assignments? why can i use it in the same helper?**

```
  def current_employee=(employee)
    @current_employee = employee
  end

  def current_employee
    remember_token = Employee.hash(cookies[:remember_token])
    @current_employee ||= Employee.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
  end
```

The first one, `current_employee=(employee)`, is called a `setter`, because you set a new value on `@current_employee`. The second one, `current_employee`, is called `getter`, because you get the current value of the `@current_employee`. [More info about setters and getters](http://justintallant.com/classes-in-ruby-using-getters-and-setters/).

In the getter method, the `||=` is used for [`memoization`](http://gavinmiller.io/2013/basics-of-ruby-memoization/). So the first time you call `current_employee` the value of `Employee.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)` is assigned to `@current_employee`. In subsequent calls to the getter method, you retrieve the same value.

**2- what's the difference between these 2 update functions, and why the json needed here?**

```
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @employee.update(employee_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @employee, success: 'Employee was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @employee.errors, failure: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

and

```
def update
    @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])
    if @employee.update_attributes(employee_params)
      # Handle a successful update.
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
end
```

Both `update` methods are esentially the same. The last one is responding only to HTML format. The first example is responding to both, HTML and JSON formats. If you don't need to response to JSON format, you can stay with the last one.

Comment: @backpackerhh what do you mean by `response to JSON format`